# how do I append the inserted URL into image after the inputed text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have written the code but the jquery code isn't getting executed.

```
Enter URL :<input type="text">
<button id="btn"> continue
</button>
<div contenteditable="true"
id="bod">
Click on this text to start writting</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("btn").click(function(){
  $("bod").append($('input').html('<img alt="" src="'+$(this).val()+'">'))
    })
});
```

**Also I wanna use "input" or "textarea" instead of  since I wanna tag that field with ng-model(angularjs).**

Comment: `$("#bod")` to select for the div's ID.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your requirement correctly then JQuery code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
       var bodElem = $("#bod");
       var url = $("input").val();
       $('<img alt="" src="'+ url +'">').insertAfter(bodElem);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to accomplish:

For one, you are trying to reference your elements with an id selector without `#`.

`$("bod")` should be `$("#bod")`, etc. '#" indicates an ID.

And also the way you were retrieving the value for input was all wrong.

Also if you want the value of one item, use an ID. Otherwise you'll get an array just using a generic element selector. I gave your input an id, so you weren't just trying to get a value off of `$('input')`

(I put a placeholder image address in your value, you can remove that)

Also view the snippet full screen. The small view makes it look like your text is being removed, but it's not really.  It's just that when the img is appended, the baseline for everything is lower than the window in the snippet viewer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#bod").append('<img alt="" src="'+$('#inp').val()+'">');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter URL :<input id="inp" type="text" value="http://placehold.it/300">
<button id="btn">continue</button>
<div contenteditable="true" id="bod">Click on this text to start writting</div>
```